# Running a Twitch live stream

Tags: streaming, video-streaming

Hello guys I'm trying to find a way to live stream to twitch.tv and i been trying many methods that haven't worked so for I even think i messed up my laptop a little in the process because now my google icon wont show any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From what program, what have you tried?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? What methods have you tried? What is the exact problem you are facing? What do you mean by 'google icon wont show'?

Answer (score 0):

To watch on chromium, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

Now, restart chromium.

Comment: I believe he's trying to stream to twitch.tv and not watch.